# Strapi Navigation Internationalization: can’t save Chinese characters

Tags: navigation, internationalization, strapi, chinese-locale

I enabled internationalization in Strapi and in the Navigation Plugin. Everything works fine, until when I change “Home” to Chinese characters and click the Save button, nothing happens, but when I add an English letter or a number in front of the Chinese characters, the Save button works again.

Single-type and collection work fine with internationalization.

How can I fix this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue and solution are provided by the official team of the plugin here: https://github.com/VirtusLab-Open-Source/strapi-plugin-navigation/issues/335